# React Native(iOS) Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: ios, react-native

I am having an issue with my app stopping at the splash screen after upgrading to handle newer devices. I'm running the following.

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-native": "^0.51.0",
```

There is no error in the packager but in xCode I see the following

```
Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered 
callable module (calling runApplication)
```

and

```
[tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS 
Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.PropTypes.oneOf')
```

Any help tracking down either of these errors would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

PropTypes have been moved away from the React package in React v16 and above.

Somewhere in your code you either have `React.PropTypes` or an import statement like this  `import { PropTypes } from 'react'`

You have to change this by importing PropTypes like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
```

And use it like this.

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
 props: PropTypes.string
}
```

You also have to make sure that in your `package.json` inside of `dependencies` you have the `prop-types` dependency, for example by running:

```
npm install --save prop-types
```